# How to create custom controls in JavaFX

Tags: java, controls, javafx-8

I would like to create a custom control in JavaFX 8.It looks like a DatePicker or ColorPicker controls, but instead of showing popup list in the case of DatePicker and Color palette in the case of ColorPicker, I want to change the Popup content to show an entier Stage. Both DatePicker and ColorPicker subclass ComboBoxBase and ComboBoxPopupControl for Skining.Well i don't know if this the right way to go. So, how can i create this kind a controls.

Here is a starting point:

```
public class StagePopupControl extends ComboBoxBase<String> {
    public StagePopupControl() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new StagePopupControlSkin(this); // unfortunately the compiler shows an error "Make 'createDefaultSkin' return 'StagePopupControlSkin'"
    }
}


public class StagePopupControlSkin extends ComboBoxPopupControl<String> {

    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();


    public StagePopupControlSkin(ComboBoxBase comboBox, ComboBoxBaseBehavior behavior) {
        super(comboBox, behavior);
        root.getChildren().addAll(new DatePicker(), new TextArea());
    }

    @Override
    protected Node getPopupContent() {
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public Node getDisplayNode() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use it as cell edit in tableview, image an inventory mangement system, when the user try to fill the product, a popup combobox based widow appreas that shows a list of product for the user to choose from.

Comment: That just sounds exactly like a combo box...

Comment: I take a lot at JavaFX API, but i seems complicated to figure out how event handling mechanism is setup.